# Escaping special characters in JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

I need a method in JavaScript to escape all characters which are not ( a-z / A-Z / 0-9 / - / _ )

If the character is ø it should be replaced with oe, if it's å then replaced with aa, and more.... if characters are not on the list, they should be replaced with an underscore.

If there are 2 underscores in a row ( __ ) they should be replaced with a single underscore.

I need this done in JavaScript and/or PHP.

Comment: tanks Dav, my english its not soe good but i trying. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String.prototype.slugify = function(){
    return this.replace('ø','oe').replace('å','aa').replace(/\W/gi,'_').replace(/_+/g,'_');
}
var x = 'sdfkjshødfjsåkdhf#@$%#$Tdkfsdfxzhfjkasd23hj4rlsdf9';
x.slugify();
```

Add as many rules as you'd like following the `.replace('search','replace')` pattern. Make sure that you finish it with `.replace(/\W/gi,'_').replace(/_+/,'_')`, which converts . Also ensure you serve it up in UTF-8 to accommodate the special characters like ø.

An alternate version, suggested by Strager:

```
String.prototype.slugify = function(){
    var replacements = {
        'ø': 'oe',
        'å': 'aa'
    }
    var ret = this;
    for(key in replacements) ret = ret.replace(key, replacements[key]);
    return ret.replace(/\W/gi,'_').replace(/_+/g,'_');
}
```

This version is certainly more flexible and maintainable. I'd use this one, though I'm keeping the previous iteration for posterity. Great idea, Strager!

Comment: Also, I think you may want to add the /g flag to the underscore-collapse regexp.

Comment: When creating new string manipulation functions, I prefer to extend the `String` object to preserve chainability, etc. Good catch on the /g flag, my mistake! Edited.

Comment: By object I meant iterating through an object for replacements, like: `{ 'ø': 'oe', 'å': 'aa' }`

Comment: nice, its help just only one problem.

 var replacements = {
        'ø': 'oe',
  'Ø': 'OE',
        'å': 'aa',
  'Å': 'AA',
  'æ': 'ae',
  'Æ': 'AE'
    }

    var ret = str;

    for(key in replacements)
 {
  ret = ret.replace(key, replacements[key]);
    }
 
 document.getElementById( id ).value = ret.replace(/\W/gi,'_').replace(/_+/g,'_');

when i run it, whit this ( øøø ) its make oe_ its replace to oeoeoe and not oe_ :/ pls help here to.

Comment: You need to use http://pastebin.com - it's almost impossible to read code with linebreaks stripped like this.

Comment: The issue is `.replace` doesn't replace all occurances, just the first.  Either rewrite as `.replace(new RegExp(key, 'g'), replacements[key])` or use a loop.  (Latter requires more code but is safer.)